# Are academic publications meant to be "dry"?

Tags: publications

Are academic publications meant to be "dry"?

Or are there examples of "nice to read" papers?

Is this subjective?

Comment: Dry. On the rock is the academic career of 99% of the people in the academia.

Comment: At the very least, there are sometimes funny titles: https://www.boredpanda.com/funny-science-paper-titles/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organic

Comment: Weirdly enough, while I prefer to read "nice to read" papers (there are a few of them), I would prefer it, if most people would write "dry" papers instead. The truth is, most people in academia are not necessarily talented writers and in general dry papers are simply much harder to mess up completely.

Comment: "Nice to read" -- In my field, this could mean that the paper has a good logical reading flow, avoids overuse of the passive voice, and uses an illustrative way for explaining things (for example a walkthrough by example before doing the complicated stuff). Such papers definitely exist.

Comment: I'm trying real hard to imagine an academic paper in the style of Faulkner, particularly the chapter in The Sound and the Fury that was an all-italics stream of consciousness. On second thought, I have seen a few technical papers along those lines (albeit without the italics), and they were horrible papers...

Comment: Dry. To the point of being silly. In Economics, for decades published works mentioned the "demand" curve. But this apparently became too mundane, so they started calling it the "marginal benefit" curve. Same thing, but fancier name that undergraduates would be less likely to understand.

Answer (score 9):

> Are academic publications meant to be "dry"?

If by dry you mean unpleasant to read, then no. If you mean efficient and without superfluous “fluff,” then yes.

> Or are there examples of "nice to read" papers?

Of course, much in the same way that there is “nice to listen to” music. Writing comes in a variety of styles.

> Is this subjective?

Yes.

Comment: "If you mean efficient and without superfluous “fluff,” then yes.". I don't find this trivial at all. It's not efficient, if the paper is boring. Efficiency should be losable also to incomprehension due to not finding the reading an enjoyable activity.

Comment: Frankly, for the vast majority of papers, the time it would take to make it "enjoyable" insofar as that is possible far outweighs the loss of efficiency due to the boredom of the few who will read it.

Comment: @mantra No I think that it has to be pleasant to read in order to be usable. I had an example of a dry paper that had very much the results I needed, but I found the paper so dry and cryptically formulated (**and it came from a very experienced writer**) that I found that the results are therefore unreplicable. I therefore find that the **idea of "nice and replicable paper" is not trivial at all** and it's not achieved through being "without superfluous 'fluff'". Because sometimes the reader is not as experienced as someone may think. Then there's no room for "well, we expect you to know".

Answer (score 5):

Academic publications are meant to be informative on things that are, for most people, difficult to understand. If those things were easy to understand then they would likely have been discovered long ago and not the subject of current research.

Scientific and other scholarly works are written, primarily, for experts who are interested in the progress made, not in entertainment. They want the essence.

Some writers are good at explaining the scientific works to a more general audience, however. Carl Sagan comes to mind. But what they write aren't really scholarly works, but popular ones.

And some scientific writers are, of course, terrible writers that even the experts find difficult to decipher.

Scientific papers are also limited in length generally, so long narratives leading up to conclusions is pretty much impossible. If every paper were written like a novel, then one might expect to have them be "nice to read".

But think about any long (non-scientific) work; Harry Potter for example. If you extract the essence of the work and reduce it to 8 pages, you will probably find the result pretty "dry".

Comment: Yes you seem to grasp the main problem. Dryness results perhaps from someone's idea that "to be succinct is to be efficient".

Answer (score 3):

Different texts have different purposes. If you buy a novel, then you want to be entertained. If you read a scientific article you want information. Standards for scientific articles are there to make this transfer of information efficient even if the author is not a great writer. I think it is a good thing that these standards are very strong and deviations are very rare, since most people who think of themselves as good writers, are actually pretty bad.

Comment: Can you prove that standards for scientific articles improve outcomes? Someone could argue that they do not, since e.g. they would attempt to universalize that which is "foundationally" subjectively perceived. Thus possibly destroying something that could be great without such formatting. Destroying expressiveness.

Comment: I also don't personally agree that scientific articles would need to be dry. Since I think that people should find it pleasing to read beautiful text, rather than dry, if given the choice. Thus questioning, whether this "dryness" is a benefit or a hinderance. The worst outcome would be, I would say, that the paper is not read at all. Which is ofc possible, if it's boring.

Comment: The point is that you should read an academic article differently than a novel. Reading an article is just work. If the article has a standard format you know where to look, and you get your work done more quickly. If you start to be expressive, then the reader has to search for the needed information, which wastes her or his time. A scientific article is a very utilitarian text. If you want to be creative in your writing, write a novel. But, as sursula mentioned, there is some room for expression in the title.

Comment: But my opinion does not matter. You want to be creative, go ahead, and see if you get passed the reviewers or editors. (Be prepared to be rejected often and brutally, but that is unfortunatly good advise even you don't try to be creative)

Comment: I understand this point, but I've half-developed my own approach to this, which is that: **1) expect a reader that *wants to understand things* to read the paper and 2) have the reader make NOTES based on what he finds**. Rather than have the writer make ASSUMPTIONS about what readers are looking for. This approach is what I find is what students do when lecture notes are cryptic. You read, and you make notes for yourself.

Comment: "since most people who think of themselves as good writers, are actually pretty bad.". Is there an objective standard for this? I've found texts of experienced writers bad, why? Because people have become accustomed to different stylistic approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely.  The more adjectives you have in your paper, and/or bombastic your statements are, the less people believe you.   We have enough of those in the media.

Answer (score 0):

This has been stated a few times already, but I would expand on what @mlk said in a form of comment.

Most people, myself included, are pretty bad at writing.
One might think "oh how great would it be if scientific papers were more like posts people write on blogs or Facebook, it would be so much easier to read", but this turns a blind eye to how bad most of these blogs actually are. Many of them are utterly incomprehensible, even!
The trick here is then that one does not read *all* the blogs or consider them *all* while making this comparison - why'd they do that? Instead, they are reading *good* ones. This is not an option for something that people do as a part of their job.

Maybe if we had another few years of mandatory journalistic studies for all academicians, it would be better. But don't you find this is a bit ridiculous requirement to have? "Be good at writing or don't do science", huh?

The issue is further exacerbated by the need to write in a non-native language, which English is for many - again, myself included. I *wish* I could write better and am trying my best, but learning a small subset of language and producing dry texts full of clichés is just easier. By easier, I mean less prone to mistakes that could alter the meaning a *lot*. Saying something like *"I feel myself great today"* is awkward but is actually more innocent than leading someone to write off tens of thousands of dollars in reagents/equipment because you've provided some murky instructions.

It is more of a necessity, then, rather than a goal. People with decent command of language and confident in their skills often write quite engaging papers, and it is definitely a plus. You may even find that great, Nobel prize-level scientists are, in general, a fair bit better at delivery than their less accomplished colleagues.

Some people just don't care and it still work - one notable example of this I know of are YOLO papers; here's one example https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02767.
Google Scholar shows almost 10k citations for this one; CS/ML/AI field is a bit unique admittedly but still, sticking to formal guns didn't matter at the slightest for that one.

Even then, one thing stands out: it may be flavorful but has to be unambiguous and comprehensible. Formal writing accomplishes both. Writing "the substrate was whirling like clouds enclosing on the Malmo coast in August" may be engaging and might even provide some helpful ideas to some people about how did it actually look like, but for most, it would be *incredibly* not helpful.

A tangential: there are popsci outlets presenting research in a more digestible way, but the people writing those articles naturally talented and/or formally educated in *writing*.

TL;DR: It would be great to have more engaging and readable articles but it is too much to ask.

Comment: I really disagree. *Why* is it too much to ask that scientists write in an engaging style? I presume everyone with a PhD has had at least some education in language and literature, including creative and persuasive writing. I consider it part of my job to communicate my results clearly and effectively. Just because it's hard doesn't mean we shouldn't try!

Comment: @astronat "I presume everyone with a PhD has had at least some education in language and literature, including creative and persuasive writing" - where does that come from?! Sure, they have to pen the dissertation and learn a great deal about writing in the process, but *at least* for STEM fields here I daresay all formal education some 99% of PhDs had in language and literature they got in school. BSc/MSc students sometimes require a lot of input for their writing, to put it mildly. I've opted to not include the section about students in the answer (and deleted it), but since it came up...

Comment: ...there is still a big struggle for even PhD students in writing coherent text. First drafts lack clarity and are a result of using conversational/instant messaging "writing" experience as a basis. Unfortunately, that means that as details get added, the text becomes essentially unreadable. Writing *is* hard. 
And yes, communication is a part of the job. We absolutely should try to get better in that regard, it's just at least I personally don't have those couple extra years per group of students, and deem it unreasonable to demand it at the most basic level. Advanced training? Sure, why not